# Animate component in tag 'details'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-animate

HTML:

```css
.main-summary:before {
  content    : "+";
  font-size  : 2em;
  padding    : 0 0.5em;
  display    : inline-block;
  transition : .5s;
  color      : grey;
  transform  : rotate(0deg);
  }
summary:after {
  padding     : 0px .5em;
  text-align  : right;
  float       : right;
  display     : inline-block;
  content     : "∨";
  font-size   : .7em;
  transition  : .5s;
  width       : 90%;
  font-weight : 700;
  }
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="main-summary">
    <p>Main summary</p>
  </summary>
  <details>
    <summary>
      <p>Text in summary</p>
    </summary>
    <p>123</p>
  </details>
</details>
```

How can I make an animation for the main `<details>` tag so that the `+` sign *1 image* flips over and becomes the closing icon `X` *2 image*, and the `∨` at the end of `<details>` turned over and became an up arrow *3 image*, but this is only for the open element, and not for all that are in the open tag.

1 image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x5cD.png] 
2 image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP9ic.png] 
3 image: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMMA4.png]

Comment: While I can see how to rotate the + I do not understand what position you want the v to be in - is it to the far right or...?